# Load dropdown dynamically with user ability to add

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown I would like to load with options dynamically.  I would also like to allow the user to "add" their own option and have it save to that dynamic list.  So when anyone returns to that form, the new option is in the list.  This is what I have so far - what do I need?  Any information is greatly appreciated!

Here is my working project:
http://www.leskofolio.com/calendar/cal/gcal-script/index

The jsfiddle I was given with the ajax suggestion is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/o0qc8wvc/5/

Here is my dropdown - it doesn't pull from a dynamic "writable" list yet or, maybe it can?

```
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php if($edit) echo 'edit';else echo 'insert';?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<?php if($edit) echo $event_data['id'];else echo '0';?>">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="event_title">Surgeon Name <span class="required">*</span>       </label>
    <select name="event_title" id="event_title" class="form-control required">
    <option value="">Select a Surgeon</option>
    <option value="BERASI"> BERASI</option>
    <option value="BERGHOFF"> BERGHOFF</option>
    <option value="BIGGS"> BIGGS</option>
    <option value="BORUS"> BORUS</option>
    <option value="BURKE"> BURKE</option>
    <option value="CANNONE"> CANNONE</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <label for="event_title">Add a Surgeon</label>
    <input type="text" class="addingElement">
    <button class="addingButton" >Add</button>
    </div>
```

I was told I could use Ajax to do this but he coudldn't help me with "additional PHP" that would be needed.  Here is his ajax code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addingButton').on('click', function(){
    var newElement = $('.addingElement').val();
    console.log(newElement);
    var newOption = $('<option>').attr('value', newElement).text(newElement);
    $('#event_title').append(newOption);
    $.ajax({
            url: 'link/to/my/index.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
                'newElement': newElement
        }, success: function(data) {
            // the new element was successfully added to the database
            console.log('success ! ');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            //there was an error while adding the new element.
            console.error('there was an error : ' + error);
        }
      })
    })
 });
```

Again my selectbox works but I can't save the users addition.  What am I missing or doing wrong?  Again, any information is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to store the element they added in `localStorage.setItem()` (or cookies or something) to store their entry, then use `localStorage.getItem()` when the page loads to retrieve any stored items.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the items they've added. The simplest way to do this will be to use `localStorage`. I've modified your code to store the element they add to a `localStorage` item called `options`, then on page load, I'm reading in that `localStorage` item and populating the list.

Since SO won't allow `localStorage` to be read in the sandbox code environment, here's a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/o0qc8wvc/7/

Answer (score 0):

The new option you want to append should look like this

`Var newoption ="<option value='"+ newElement +"'>" + newElement + "</option>"`

I would recommend if you want to store it in a database after the new record has been inserted to reload the entire list -- remove the old options and load in the entire list --